# Generate a UUID as hex-string inserted into the code editor in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, uuid

I like to attach a hard-coded [hex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) string representing a [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) value in my error messages and logging calls.

Is there a way for IntelliJ to generate a UUID ([Version 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_.28random.29), all random) and insert at the cursor in the code editor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[UUID Generator](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8320-uuid-generator) plug-in should help.

Choose `Preferences`/`Settings` > `Plugins` > `Browse repositories…` (button). Enter `UUID` in the search-field to see a list of plugins that you can install.

Comment: Thanks! Found three such plugins in the JetBrains Plugins Repository: [*UUID Generator*](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8320-uuid-generator?), [*UUIDMaker*](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8622-uuidmaker), [*UUID Plugin*](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1188-uuid-plugin). The one you linked, *UUID Generator*, seems to be the most actively developed.

Answer (score 1):

The [Jetbrains Test Data Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/16873-test-data) also has support for generating UUIDs (in addition to other random data).

It works by pressing Ctrl/Cmd + N